# PIC167877A with 74HC595 Shift Register using SPI

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, shift-register

HI I'm trying to implement simple spi communication to turn on 8 led connected to shift register can amy one help me whats wrong with this code, im getting random output, I want to send 0x02 to turn on led(00000010) .

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "spi.h"
#pragma config WDTE = OFF  // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF   // Low-Voltage In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit
#pragma config CPD = OFF   // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit 
#pragma config WRT = OFF   // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits 
#pragma config CP = OFF    // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
void main()
{
        char data = 0x10;
        spiInit(SPI_MASTER_OSC_DIV4, SPI_DATA_SAMPLE_END, SPI_CLOCK_IDLE_LOW, SPI_IDLE_2_ACTIVE);
        TRISC0 = 0;
        RC0 = 1;
        RC3 = 0;
        RC5 = 0;
        while(1)
        {
                RC0 = 0;       //Slave Select
                __delay_ms(100);
                spiWrite(data);
                while(!SSPSTATbits.BF);
                __delay_ms(100);
                RC0= 1;       //Slave Deselect 
        }
}
```

Comment: My connection
ST_CP(LATCH) of shift register to PORTC0
SH_CP( CLOCK) to PORTC3(SCK)
DS(Data select) to PORTC5(SDO)

and link to spi.c and libraries
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XOx7Gcmv69lJFw0_TEZcVmU4d2KRBxS4

Comment: you are sending 0x10 but you want out put as 0x02 is that correct?

Comment: What is the maximum speed supported by shift register

Comment: Can you state the shift register part no.? You need to look from the slave side  when you configure the master.  The code looks Ok except for the 'data' you assigned 0x10. You need to look for Speed, Spi_Transmit_Edge,Spi_Clock_Idle from the slave side, what is it looking for. BTW - SDI is not connected? i hope you are not trying SPI when it is actually i2c?

Comment: @Sudhee sorry just a small mistake any data is fine but I'm getting all led turned on whatever i send

Comment: @Sudhee 74HC595 no need to connect sdi pin as I'm not bothered about reception from slave this shift register have latch pin which is connected to RC0 it'll latch out data stored in SDO

Comment: As far as I can tell 74HC595 is not using SPI interface. You may need to use concept called 'Bitbanging' [link]https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut  shows some examples, but this is with different controller, surely will give idea or what you are missing in your code

Comment: @Sudhee yeah bit banging works but I'm trying with spi in pic same 74HC595 i tried with arm7 spi configuration it worked perfectly http://www.electroons.com/ARM/lpc21xx_spi.html      I'm trying to implement this configuration in pic controller always getting junk value